# How to sort or Orderby in firstore android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a sorter for stores where they have an `index` which will indicate their position. But when I tried:

```
Query storeQuery = db.collection("Stores")
    .whereEqualTo("online", true).orderBy("index", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

It is not working and I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: Above statement works, you just have wrong order. Right?

Comment: It works when i removed the orderby. What is the correct order sir?

Comment: What you mean by `index` it's name of the column? Because you could try to replace with primary key, field with name `_id`.

Comment: `index` is the total count of the stores then added by 1 which was you can call their key but not. Because these indexes will only represent their orders. Another thing that will prove that this is not their `id` because this will change every day or these `id`s will be jumbled. Basically this is their key so the buyer will saw different stores every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not working and I don't know why is this happening.

When you try to query a collection using both `whereEqualTo()` and `orderBy()` methods on different fields, please note that your query will **not** work unless you create an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for it. This can be done, by creating it manually in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) or if you are using Android Studio, you'll find in your logcat a message that sounds like this:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...
```

You can simply click on that link or copy and paste the url into a web broswer and you index will be created automatically.